# Не обновляется словарь dict в Python

Tags: python, словари

Есть словарь Name, Изначально значение у него такое

```
{'Натариус': 0, 'Traiding': 3, 'Бар Шелк': 17, и т д}
```

Потом запускаю цикл по файлу excel, добавляю в список и хочу обновить список

```
for v in name:
    for row in range(name[v], row_number):
        if (str(sheet.row(row)[1]).find("empty") < 0):
            l.append(str(sheet.row(row)[1]).replace("text:", "").replace("'", ""))
            #print(str(sheet.row(row)[1]).replace("text:", "").replace("'", ""))
        else:
            name.update({v: l})
            l.clear()
            break
```

Но он почему то постоянно обновляет записи по изначальному ключу.
Вот пример работы. Первый шаг

```
l = ['244 66 14', '244 66 15']
name = {'Натариус': ['244 66 14', '244 66 15'], 'Traiding': 3, 'Бар Шелк': 17, и т д}
```

Супер список обновился.
Но когда проходит второй раз по циклу, то выходят такие значения

```
l = ['244 66 00', '244 66 01', '244 66 02', '244 66 03', '244 66 04', '244 66 05', '244 66 06', '244 66 48', '244 66 47', '244 67 25', '244 67 15', '244 66 13', '244 66 87'] #все верно
name = {'Натариус': ['244 66 00', '244 66 01', '244 66 02', '244 66 03', '244 66 04', '244 66 05', '244 66 06', '244 66 48', '244 66 47', '244 67 25', '244 67 15', '244 66 13', '244 66 87'], 'Traiding': ['244 66 00', '244 66 01', '244 66 02', '244 66 03', '244 66 04', '244 66 05', '244 66 06', '244 66 48', '244 66 47', '244 67 25', '244 67 15', '244 66 13', '244 66 87'], 'Бар Шелк': 17, и т д} # не верно
```

Он обновился по первому ключу и второму. Итд по списку, он постоянно обновляет по всем ключам а не выбранном.

Где ошибка?

Comment: Как создаётся словарь `name`? Скорее всего, Вы копируете ссылку на один и тот же экземпляр списка.

Comment: В начале создаю так name = dict(), потом наполняю его name[str(sheet.row(row)[0]).replace("text:", "").replace("'", "")] = row, ну а потом код такой какой вы видите. @nomnoms12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы добавляете не копию списка, а **ссылку** на список. Чтобы этого избежать, можно брать полный срез, так как срез всегда возвращает новый объект:

```py
name.update({v: l[:]})
```

Comment: Получилось спасибо. Но если честно не понял ничего того что вы написали, буду благодарен если вы расширите ответ или комментарий

Comment: @duddeniska Это довольно обширная тема. Рекомендую прочитать [статью на хабре](https://habr.com/ru/post/49671/), а именно раздел "Списки и словари", там всего несколько абзацев, но описано очень хорошо и с примерами.

Comment: ну да, я понял, если я присваю по имени другой объект словаря. Просто я работаю с одним словарем Name. С начало я добавил туда данные, а потом пытался обновить. Получается если я делаю срез то он мне возвращает новый объект. А если у меня 100 таких действий, в памяти будет 100 объектов?

Comment: Поэтому не понятно, я ж вроде с одним dict работаю @nomnoms12

Comment: @duddeniska Дело не в `dict`, дело в `list`. Списков должно быть много, потому что предполагается, что они разные. Но по факту Вы работаете только с одним, добавляя в словарь **ссылки** на него. Если сделаете 100 срезов (то есть создадите 100 списков), то будет 100 разных объектов. Это нормально.

Comment: Блин стремно переспрашивать, но все же. Добавил в List l.append(str(sheet.row(row)[1]).replace("text:", "").replace("'", "")), ниже очистил l.clear() . Т.е. l.clear() не очищает список?

Comment: @duddeniska `l.clear()` очищает список. Если в словаре хранятся ссылки на него, то Вы увидите, что все (по факту один) списки очищены.

Comment: Блин спасибо большое понял. в PHP таких проблем не было @nomnoms12